# sixteen columns grid layout: 2nd div won't push to the right

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am modifying my website that uses a style sheet with a sixteen column grid layout. I am trying to make a custom page where the left side is big, and the right side is more or less a narrower sidebar:

http://tecinfrared.com/the-backyard-development-ii/

screen shot:
[image]

Here is my simple html so far:

```
<div class="sixteen columns"><!-- Sixteen Columns Layout Start -->

    <div class="twelve columns" style="background-color:#ff9900;">
         left
    </div>
    <div class="four columns" style="background-color:#99ff00;">
         right
    </div>

</div><!-- Sixteen Columns Layout End -->
```

What I expect to happen is that the "right" div (lime colored) lines up to the right of the "left" or orange div. I have made a page that uses floats, but the problem is it's not responsive, so on mobile devices the sidebar div has to push below the left column div.

I thought this css & html should work similar to Zurb's Foundation responsive framework, where the divs will drop vertically for smaller screens, but line up horizontally for wider screens.

Comment: I don't know anything about your grid system...but why are you nesting everything within the `sixteen columns` div? Getting rid of that wrapper may fix the problem.

Comment: @mevius Removed, but doesn't change anything.

Comment: Where did your skeleton base come from?  It's not any framework from what I can tell.  It looks like it's missing some key code that would make the columns float, display as inline/inline-block, or display as flex.

Comment: @JosephMarikle I inherited this theme, so I didn't write the skeleton_base.css. Your observation may explain my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this CSS

```
.columns {
  display: inline-block;
 }
```

in order to allow side-by-side display of these elements.

And if you don't like the margins between the elements, also add `margin: 0 !important;` to that rule.

Comment: Works like magic, even in responsive views. Upvoted, selected as best answer Johannes.